# How to make a Responsive ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to make a responsive website and I have a problem with the navbar.
I have 4 items in my nav and I want to them to respond when the screen size gets smaller (they are by default vertical and when on the size changing they become horizontal). I wonder if there is a way to do this with CSS?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav{
  list-style-type:none;
    display: flex; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w1"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w2"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w3"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w4"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you want to happen instead? Your html is invalid, too. an `a` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. those links need to go in the `li`

Comment: you mean a tag must be in li ? sorry my english is not good

Comment: @majidmashmool That's correct, you should put your `<a>` tags inside your `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Media Queries. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Also, your list should be like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href=""> CONTENT HERE </a></li>
   <li><a href=""> CONTENT HERE </a></li>
   <li><a href=""> CONTENT HERE </a></li>
</ul>
```

Use W3C Validator to check your HTML, they'll give you a super detailed list of what is wrong and what is right: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries or just use bootstrap I made a responsive example for you using bootstrap 
**vertical example**

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <ul class="nav list-group"><li class="list-group-item">  <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w1"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
            
                       <li class="list-group-item"> <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive"  src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w2"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                      <li class="list-group-item">  <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w3"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                     <li class="list-group-item">   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w4"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                    </ul>
```

**horizontal example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="list-inline"><li>  <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w1"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
        
                   <li> <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive"  src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w2"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                  <li>  <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w3"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                 <li>   <a href="#"<li><div class="wrap"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/fantasy_32-t2.jpg" alt="wd" width="200" height="200" class="w4"><span class="web"></span></div></li></a>
                </ul>
```